# Div not stretching together with child divs?

Tags: css, html, layout, stretch

Here is my example:
[wthdesign.net/website/olaf&co/index.php](http://wthdesign.net/website/olaf&co/index.php)

I'm creting a responsive layout, but somehow I can't figure out how to stretch "#content" together with the child div when there is more content then expencted...

Comment: Add `overflow:hidden;` to #content. That's how you make parents of floated elements stretch to include all floated children. It screws up your images though, so just figure out how to tile those horizontally as well.

Comment: I have tried add overflow:hidden to it but it somehow crop off my text rather than stretching the content div..

Comment: That doesn't happen to me. What size window do you get that effect in?

Answer (score 1):

nvm I got it working, this is because my #mainContentArea is using position absolute, by removing it and add overflow hidden to #content and everything works...